# Error en código de html y javascript para emitir alerta con los checkbox marcados

Tags: javascript, html

Necesito elaborar un código de html en el que aparezcan diversos checkbox y un botón y con un script que cuando se pulse el botón aparezca un mensaje con los que se han presionado. Este tendría que ser el resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo el código que he realizado no da respuesta.
Os adjunto el código:

```
<html> 
  <script language="JavaScript"> 
    function calculs(){ 
      var football = "";
      var basket = "";
      var swimming = "";
      if(document.getElementById("checkbox1").checked{ football = "Football"; } 
      if(document.getElementById("checkbox2").checked{ basket = "Basket"; } 
      if(document.getElementById("checkbox3").checked{ football = "Swimming"; } 
      alert("The selected sports are" + Football + " " + Basket + " " + Swimming);
    } 
  </script> 
  <h1>Cube exercise</h1> 
  <form> 
    <p><input type="checkbox" id="password">Football</p>
    <p><input type="checkbox" id="password">Basket</p>
    <p><input type="checkbox" id="password">Swimming</p>
    <input type="button" value="Send" onClick="calculs()" > <br>
  </form> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Puedes envolver todos los elementos que son elegibles dentro de un div  y a este mismo darle una clase
- Posterior hacemos un *listener* al evento `click` de este mismo elemento para que sea a través de este que identifiquemos que elementos activó el evento `click`
- Como deseamos almacenar que eligió el usuario entonces en un array previamente declarado entonces los recuperamos con la sintaxis de: `evento.target.value`
- Posterior al final con el evento `click` del botón del formulario imprimimos el array recién llenado con los elementos elegidos por el usuario

Código:

```html
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
          <title>JS Bin</title>
        </head>
        <body>
        <html> 
        
          <h1>Cube exercise</h1> 
          <form> 
            <div class="listado">
              <p><input type="checkbox" value="FootBall" id="password">Football</p>
              <p><input type="checkbox" value="Basket" id="password">Basket</p>
              <p><input type="checkbox" value="Swimming" id="password">Swimming</p>
            </div>
            <input id="envio" type="button" value="Send"> <br>
          </form> 
        </html>
          <script> 
            let listado = document.querySelector(".listado")
            let boton   = document.getElementById("envio")
            let elegidos = []
            listado.addEventListener("click", (evento) => {
             if(!evento.target.value == "") {
               elegidos.push(evento.target.value)
             }
            })
            
            boton.addEventListener("click", () => {
              alert(elegidos)
            })
          </script> 
        </body>
        </html>
```

> Hacemos uso de un condicional para evaluar que el atributo `value` sea distinto de "" ya que por la estructura de la propuesta si el usuario da click en alguna parte que no sean los elementos pudiera generar que el array se llene de valores *undefined*

**EDICIÓN**

Ahora como yo indiqué que voy a obtener el texto del atributo `value` al dar click a los elementos dentro del `div` si por error doy click en algún espacio sin inputs dentro de este generaré que se obtenga un valor `undefined` por eso hice la validación con el if/else para prevenir que esos valores entren al array.

Por otro lado los eventos se disparán dentro de la página web cuando el usuario ejerce alguna acción sobre uno o varios elementos de tu web, por ejemplo cuando el usuario de click en los checkbox es un evento y cuando presionas el botón del formulario es otro evento.

Para el último punto me interesa el evento `click` del botón por que cuando el usuario lo presione yo quiero que se muestren los valores elegidos; entonces hago uso de un listener que es un *escuchador* de dichos eventos el cual con la sintaxis mostrada pide: **evento** y **función con las acciones a realizar cuando el usuario provoque dicho evento**.

**REFERENCIAS**

- [Eventos en JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Eventos)
- [Método addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Comment: Debes declarar para que sea mas simple obtener el valor de texto deseado, este mismo como valor del atributo `value` de cada uno de tus `inputs`

Comment: Resulta que tengo bastante poco nivel de programación y me pierdo con todo lo de los listeners, evento.target.value, queryselector.... si me pudieras explicar todo más paso a paso te lo agradecería ^^